# Implement Claim based authentication

Tags: claims-based-auth, claim-provider

I need some guidance about how to implement Claim based authentication. I need to enable my users to login using windows **LiveId** or **google id**...

Can any one share the Powershell script to achieve this requirement?

Comment: solution is in sharepoint 2010...

Comment: This should be on the main site, not meta.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official guide found on MSDN [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/library/ff973117.aspx). It's too long to copy here but basically you will need to:

- Configure the Windows Live ID Security Token Service with Microsoft Services Manager
- Install the X509 certificate on the Sharepoint server (you could also use an self-signed one).
- Configure your site to use claim auth from the windows live id provider .
- (Optional: you may be required to pass Microsoft certification for a prod environment)

You can also have a look to [Wictor visual guide](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-guide-to-Windows-Live-ID-authentication-with-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx) on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but the problem is i am not able to follow Wictor visual guide. Because it asks for domain name, i just working in intranet region....

Comment: MSDN link point to a "Page not found" error.

Comment: Tested both links and they work.

Comment: Nice summary -> +1